# Is it possible to cast the Elapsed Time function to Integer?

Tags: string, time, casting, clojure, integer

I have the following function:

```
(def elapsedtime (with-out-str (time (run-my-function))))
```

and I was wondering if is possible to store only the integer value of the time, as I can only store a String at the moment....

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**

```
So I did use this:
  (defmacro nsecs
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))]
     ~expr
     (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)))
```

And then modified this:

```
(def elapsedtime (nsecs (run-my-function argument1 argument2)))
```

but doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: main$fn--105$nsecs"

Comment: I see your definition of nsecs is different from Jan's.  Perhaps you should try using Jan's.  It works for me.

Comment: I tried his version as well, but nothing changed. the problem is in the number of arguments. Even if I do "(def elapsedtime (nsecs (+ 1 1)))" it does not work....strange

Comment: What environment are you running this in?  Can you start a REPL from the command line, without using the rest of your Clojure code, and check whether the macro has the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DefMacro solutions was not working for me, so I used this filtering solution:

```
(filter #(#{\0,\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9,\.} %) my-double-number)
```

The returned value is exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyway for your suggestions and for your time. Chers

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extracting this value from a string, let's take a look at the source of the [`time` macro](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/time).

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Elapsed time: "
               (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000.0) " msecs"))
     ret#))
```

Use it as a base for a new macro returning number of nanoseconds spent on evaluation of a given expression.

```
(defmacro nsecs
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))]
     ~expr
     (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but I am now having this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: main$fn--105$nsecs" could you have a look at the question update? thanks a lot anyway